# Rails views: how to prevent empty HTML tags from being output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

Often times in HTML I have to output e.g. a list of links like this:

```
/ Note: SLIM template!
ul
  - if can? :edit, User
    li Create
  - if can? :destroy, User
    li Destroy
```

This leads to empty `ul` tags being output when both `can?`s return false. What's a common pattern to prevent this? The only thing I can think of is the following:

```
- if edit = can?(:edit, User) && destroy = can?(:destroy, User)
  ul
    - if edit
      li Create
    - if destroy
      li Destroy
```

But this looks clumsy to me. Any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm amazed to see people are finally preferring slim over haml. I really like slim over erb and haml.

Secondly, I think this code:

```
- if edit = can?(:edit, User) && destroy = can?(:destroy, User)
  ul
    - if edit
      li Create
    - if destroy
      li Destroy
```

will not output `ul` if there either `edit` or `destroy` is false.

In such conditions, I prefer to use helper methods(because you move your logic there and keep views clean):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def show_content_for(user)
    contents = []
    contents << "Create" if can? :edit, user
    contents << "Destroy" if can? :destroy, user
    content_tag :ul do
      contents.collect { |content| concat(content_tag(:li, content)) }
    end unless contents.blank?
  end
end
```

in slim view:

```
= show_content_for User
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. But I'd like to have some general solution which doesn't force me to create a helper for each specific situation. I'm thinking about some helper like `content_tag` which strips empty tags automatically...?

Comment: PS: I love SLIM since 2 years, but my co-workers are ignorant and I couldn't convince them to take a look at SLIM. Now I quit my job and working only with SLIM.

Answer (score 0):

Build the list of allowed actions first and then do the output.

I am not sure about SLIM syntax. I use HAML.

```
- allowed = []
- if can? :edit, User
  allowed << li Create
- if can? :destroy, Use
  allowed << li Destroy

- if allowed.count
  ul
  - allowed.each do |l|
  l
```

Comment: I think all sort of logic in views should be completely avoided. Okay, one could move this into the controller, but this would become quite a mess fast.

Comment: PS: you should take a look at SLIM. I used HAML for years and turned my back completely on it since knowing about SLIM. ;-)